# Karate - difficulties with <select> in feature file that is called from different feature file using IF condition

Tags: automated-tests, karate

using Karate features I have complications with using scripts in different feature file when IF condition is used while using selection from ....

I have **main feature file** including this call:

```
karate.call('../common/connectionDeployment2.feature', {service : '#(servName1)' , con : 'connections.connections[0].managedComponentId'})}
```

and it leads to another feature file **connectionDeployment2.feature**:

```
* script("document.getElementById('connections.connections[1].managedComponentId').value='" + service.toLowerCase().replace(' ','-') + "'")
* script("document.getElementById('connections.connections[1].managedComponentId').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('change', {bubbles: true}))")
```

All mentioned above work fine. But I need to create **If condition**:

```
* if (numberOfSelects == 2) {karate.call('../common/connectionDeployment2.feature', {service : '#(servName1)' , con : 'connections.connections[0].managedComponentId'})}
```

But when I do this (condition is fulfilled), the test passes but the selection does not work in reality - no option is chosen in select.

Do you have any idea how to do this to work properly? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is too much complication. Anyway try this:

```
* if (numberOfSelects == 2) karate.call(true, '../common/connectionDeployment2.feature', {service : '#(servName1)' , con : 'connections.connections[0].managedComponentId'})
```

Refer https://github.com/intuit/karate#call-vs-read

Otherwise I have no other suggestions, maybe try using JS within the same feature.